# multiple loop for in python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I need help I create this dataframe:

[image]

And i need to create a new column with this function:

```
def pgto(x, num):
    if x == "(i)":
        return num
    elif x == "(ii)":
        return 750000.00
    elif x == "(iii)":
        return num * 0.7
    else:
        return 3000000.00
```

then i aplicate a multiple loop for:

```
for x in df_final["Tipo"]:
    for num in df_final["Valor_float"]:
        df_final["Pgto"] = pgto(x, num)
```

But the result was it:

[image]

What i should do?

Comment: try printing the contents of the "Tipo" column and take note what type they are. Bc I think it applies an automatic cask which doesnt mean x and (i) equal. Also you might wanna do things via indexes rather them this for each style.

Answer (score 1):

You are not correctly looping over rows, I'd suggest the following:

```
for idx, row in df_final.iterrows(): #Proper way to loop over rows
    # with the idx value (~row number), you can store the output value of your function
    df_final.loc[idx, "Pgto"] = pgto(row['Tipo'], row['Valor_float'])
```

Comment: Many tks! You are the guy!!